# Cannot chown, chmod on mounted ntfs partition

Tags: mount, fstab, ntfs

I need to mount a ntfs partition and be able to use it with unix file system permissions. The problem is that, when I mount the partition using the following fstab entry, I cannot run chown and chmod successfully. It executes without error, but the file access rights are not changed.

```
PARTUUID=c3e3b171-d451-44e6-9f17-ffbe9e220dc7   /mnt/mounted_drive  ntfs-3g  defaults,umask=0022,uid=1000,gid=1000,errors=remount-ro,permissions 0 2
```

When I mount the partition without setting umask, uid, and gid I can use previously mentioned commands successfully.

```
PARTUUID=c3e3b171-d451-44e6-9f17-ffbe9e220dc7   /mnt/mounted_drive  ntfs-3g  defaults,errors=remount-ro,permissions 0 2
```

What shall I do to mount the partition properly?

Comment: On Unix-like operating systems such as Linux, MacOS, BSD, etc, you can run `chown` and `chmod` on `ntfs` filesystems but they aren't going to have any effect on the actual permissions. Does the filesystem absolutely need to be `ntfs`?

Comment: I've read that the permissions option in fstab entry allows you to use permissions but without compatibility with windows, which I don't need. It seemed to work with the second mount.
In the future I am planning to reformat the partition to ext4, but currently don't have free space to backup the data.

Comment: The `permissions` option just allows permissions and rights to be set with individual files and options inside which is default. The command will work on an `ntfs` filesystem but it will have no effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With NTFS-3G, setting the owning user and group seems only to be possible when a UserMapping file containing a mapping for the targeted user/group is present.  This is not really clear from the documentation, but I'm testing it just now and that is what is happening.

If compatibility with an existing Windows installation is not needed, create an empty file `.NTFS-3G/UserMapping` on the mounted partition and fill it via:

```
getRUI4() { od -An -N4 -tu4 /dev/random | tr -d ' '; }
USERMAPPING=/media/NTFS_PARTITION/.NTFS-3G/UserMapping
echo ":users:S-1-5-21-$(getRUI4)-$(getRUI4)-$(getRUI4)-513" | sudo tee -a $USERMAPPING >/dev/null
echo "$(id -un):$(id -gn):S-1-5-21-$(getRUI4)-$(getRUI4)-$(getRUI4)-1001" | sudo tee -a $USERMAPPING >/dev/null
```

If you want to use existing Windows SIDs, you can instead use the program `ntfsusermap` on an unmounted (!) partition, which will interactively ask you to specify user- and group-names (do not need to be numeric, regardless of the message) for given paths where it first finds an as of yet unmapped ID.  This is quick to do.

User and group `root` is mapped by default, as is `other`.  The above lines will create a mapping for `users` group, and the current user.  Repeat as necessary.

Also, in my case, I mount the drive with the options

```
no_def_opts,allow_other,acl,nodev,nosuid,big_writes,hide_dot_files
```

However, in your case you should not need any of them, although I find that these options improve upon the default, as otherwise for instance `chown/chmod` fail silently in case of errors.

Comment: Perhaps you could add a reference link such as: https://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/ownership-and-permissions/#usermapping  ?

Comment: That is a nice page, and I'll also recheck whether the comment "the last number in the SID must be greater than the equivalent number for any explicitly mapped user" makes my "all must be explicit" issue goes away. This would more or less make my whole answer obsolete ^_^

Comment: Before reading your answer I didn't know it was possible heh. *Then* I looked at tuxera.