# Permission issue

Tags: permissions, chmod, ntfs

I am using an NTFS filesystem on a separate partition on Debian 9. I would like to change the permissions recursively in one directory on that filesystem. 
This are the current permissions:

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 dic  7 14:29 armv7l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  126 dic  7 14:29 brprintconflsr3 -> /opt/brother/Printers/MFCL2710DN/lpd/x86_64/brprintconflsr3
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 dic  7 14:29 i686
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 6698 jul 18  2017 lpdfilter
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  112 dic  7 14:29 rawtobr3 -> /opt/brother/Printers/MFCL2710DN/lpd/x86_64/rawtobr3
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 dic  7 14:29 x86_64
```

I execute this command:

```
sudo chmod 751 MFCL2710DN/*
```

Unfortunately the permissions does not change to rwx rx x as I would expect. Nothing happen. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Use the **-R** switch: `sudo chmod -R 751 MFCL2710DN`

Comment: @ajgringo619 Unfortunately the permissions do not change

Comment: Which permissions are you trying to change? Is the aforementioned directory list what's inside MFCL2710DN?

Comment: @ajgringo619 I am trying to change from rwxrwxrwx to rwx rx x. Yes, those files are inside the folder

Comment: The `sudo chmod -R 751 ` works, can't say why it's not working for you. Are you *sure* you're in the right directory when you call it? What happens if you use the full path? Btw, this will not affect the permissions on the links.

Comment: @ajgringo619 Yes, I also tried the absolute path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101922/discussion-between-birdman-and-ajgringo619).

Comment: What type of filesystem is this directory stored upon? Is it a Windows filesystem or something mounted from a remote location?

Comment: @Kusalananda it is a separated ntfs partition

Comment: Related on AskUbuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/491098/cannot-chown-chmod-on-mounted-ntfs-partition

Comment: Also here: [chown not working in mounted partition](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/389990)

Answer (score -1):

you should use -R or --recursive as suggested above. but also you may need to change
ownership of files/directories with chown (and -R or --recursive) before changing permissions, then change permissions.  also checkout setacl/getacl command for changing permissions.

Comment: When I posted my comment about the -R switch, the filesystem type had not been posted (had assumed EXT4). Since NTFS ignores Linux/UNIX permissions, it won't work.

Comment: thanks for the down vote.  i still think it's a problem with file/directory ownership.

Comment: It is, but Linux commands have no effect on NTFS partitions.