# Being owned by chown

Tags: ntfs, chown

The terminal excerpt is pretty much self-explanatory.  I'm logged in as root (for illustration purposes only!), I want to change ownership of a file on a mounted NTFS partition, and it doesn't work.  I admit it is late, but I'm pretty sure this should have.

Any idea what's going on here?

```
root@raspberrypi:/mnt/red/backups# ls -l
total 2613
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1359921 Nov 20 01:38 db_2020_11_20.zip
root@raspberrypi:/mnt/red/backups# chown -v chris:chris db_2020_11_20.zip
changed ownership of 'db_2020_11_20.zip' from root:root to chris:chris
root@raspberrypi:/mnt/red/backups# ls -l
total 2613
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1359921 Nov 20 01:38 db_2020_11_20.zip
root@raspberrypi:/mnt/red/backups#
```

**Added:** Note that /mnt/red is an NTFS partition.

Comment: Possibly related/helpful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11757 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/491098

Comment: Well, that's a bummer, but it looks like it's an NTFS problem.