# Can not change file permissions even as root in USB/Pen-drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, files, permissions, ntfs

I am unable to change the file permission of a file located on my NTFS style partition USB neither as Owner/user nor as root Running `ll` command [image: command output]

Running `sudo chmod 774 -v insertion.cpp`
[image: output]

Again running `ll` command
[image: same output]

Comment: You can also check this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/491098/cannot-chown-chmod-on-mounted-ntfs-partition

Answer (score -1):

NTFS doesn't support Linux permissions.

You need to use any Linux file system (such as ext4) to support Linux permissions.

Comment: So is there no way for me to change file permission on my ntfs usb with my linux system without converting it to fat32 or ext4

Comment: FAT file systems will have the same deficiencies as NTFS (they are Windows file systems). See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/491098/cannot-chown-chmod-on-mounted-ntfs-partition for a possible workround?

Comment: That's **incorrect**, check this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/491098/cannot-chown-chmod-on-mounted-ntfs-partition